# Get neighbors of a node that can be reached with n jumps (edges)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get all of the nodes and relationships of a node up to n jumps(edges). Meaning that what are the nodes that I can reach with e.g., n edges, and what are the relations in between each node.

Assume that my entire graph looks like the following: `s-[r1]-x-[r2]-n`, where s, x and n are nodes, and r1 and r2 are relations.

The following query returns entire paths going from "s" to "n":

```
MATCH (s:Type1 {id: "some_id"})-[r*1..2]-(n)
RETURN s,r,n
// please note that I don't necessarily mean 1..2 connections
// it should be generalizable to 1..n
```

It returns:

1. s-r1-x
2. s-(r1 and r2)-n

However, what I want is:

1. s-r1-x
2. x-r2-n

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

To get info on all nodes and relationships up to a specified depth (say, 5), you can use a query like this:

```
MATCH (:Type1 {id: "some_id"})-[rs*..5]->()
UNWIND rs AS r
WITH DISTINCT r
RETURN STARTNODE(r) AS s, r, ENDNODE(r) AS n
```

Comment: In terms of what it returns, this is what I want. But I didn't mean 2 neighbors explicitly. How can I generalize this to n neighbors, and automate it with one query?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture paths as follows:

```
MATCH p=(:Type1 {id: "some_id"})-[*1..2]-()
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't mean the entire paths. If you see the example in my question, I meant getting each `node-relation-node` triples separately in a different row.